# Android Studio 3.2 RC02 issue: CreateProcess error=2

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 3.2 RC2 says issue: `CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. Checked paths of Gif and SDK, it's ok. Updated to latest SDK, but error still appears. IDE do not say which file is absent. Any suggestions?

```
07.09.2018 14:39    Gradle sync started

14:40   Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (16 s 950 ms)
14:48   Executing tasks: [assemble]  
14:48   Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 704 ms
```

Comment: When does it say that? Which file is specified? Does it happen on a stable version?

Comment: You should show your idea.log, reffer to this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files

Comment: Since it's `RC2` and beta, you can't expect the app to work properly. Instead, you can try removing .gradle folder then testing..

Comment: Guys, please look at updated post

Comment: So I had to use stable version to solve this